# Meaning of var t={}; Variable equals curly braces

Tags: javascript, variables, var

I’m very new to JavaScript, and have recently learned about declaring variables with `var`. like `var a = 12` or whatever. But, I came across a line in some code for a website I was reading through for fun which read `var t={};`. 
This was actually only the second line of code.
I can’t seem to find any explanation online anywhere for what it means to set a variable to equal a set of empty curly braces.
I thought it might be a way of declaring an array or something??

Comment: `{}` is an empty object.

Answer (score 5):

This defines a variable as an empty object

```
var t = {}
```

This defines it as an empty array

```
var t = []
```

This defines it as a boolean

```
var t = true
```

This defines it as an empty string

```
var t = ''
```

This defines it as an integer(number)

```
var t = 0
```

These are the basic building blocks/data types of javascript. There are plenty of tutorials online which cover this in the first lesson.

https://javascript.info/object

https://javascript.info/types

An object is a collection of data, it can contain arrays, booleans, strings, integers and even other objects. Objects consist of key/value pairs:

```js
var user = { 
  // the key here is name and the value is a string 'Tom'
  name: 'Tom', 
  // the value can also be an integer
  age: 23,
  // or an array
  interests: ['gaming','travel','guitar'], 
  // or a boolean
  loggednIn: false,
  // or a nested object
  contact: { 
    email: 'tom@gmail.com',
    number: 01296714100
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`var` is one keyword from javascript language, used to define variable. Below is an explanation from [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

> The var statement declares a variable, optionally initializing it to a value

Statement `var t={};` means a new variable called `t` defined with initialised value is `{}`. The `{}` is literal for empty object, [more explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics).

---

TL;DR; empty object created, stored in newly created variable `t`.

Answer (score 0):

It works to initialize an object.

For example, if you declare:

`var a = {}`

and get the type using `typeof(a)` you going to get `object`. 
Different to:

`var b = 1` - `typeof(b)` is equals to `number`
`var c = foo` - `typeof(c)` is equals to `string`

And as object you can declare more complex variables, like

```
var a = { 'stackoverflowName':'mrmins', 'url':'https://stackoverflow.com', 'gender':'mygender'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let user = new Object(); // "object constructor" syntax
let user = {};  // "object literal" syntax
```

Usually, the figure brackets {...} are used. That declaration is called an object literal.

Please go through the following article for more clarity
https://javascript.info/object